# How to catch Execution Report from server using quickfixj-spring-boot-starter?

Tags: spring-boot, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Collegues, I am sending `NewOrderSingle` message to server, server recives message and send response (Execution Report (35=8)):

```
public void sendOrderMessageToServer( ) throws ConfigError, InterruptedException {

         clientInitiator.start();


        SessionID sessionID = clientInitiator.getSessions().stream()
                .filter(id -> id.getBeginString().equals(BEGINSTRING_FIX44))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);


        NewOrderSingle newOrderSingle = new NewOrderSingle();

        newOrderSingle.set(new ClOrdID(fixApiCommons.generateClOrdID(newOrderSingle)));
        newOrderSingle.set(new Side(Side.BUY));
        ......
        newOrderSingle.set(new OrdType(OrdType.MARKET));
        newOrderSingle.set(new TimeInForce(TimeInForce.FILL_OR_KILL));


        boolean send = clientQuickFixJTemplate.send(newOrderSingle, sessionID);


        log.info("Result: {}", send);

    }
```

This method result is `true` in unit test, but i don't see server's response (Execution Report (35=8)) in log.

I have `ApplicationListener` class:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ApplicationListener {


    @EventListener
    public void handleCreate(Create create) {
        log.info("onCreate: SessionId={}", create.getSessionId());
    }


    @EventListener
    public void handleLogon(Logon logon) {

        log.info("onLogon: SessionId={}", logon.getSessionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleLogout(Logout logout) {
        log.info("onLogout: SessionId={}", logout.getSessionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleToAdmin(ToAdmin toAdmin) {

        try {
            if (toAdmin.getMessage().getHeader().getString(35).equals("A")) {


                toAdmin.getMessage().setString(554, "*******");
                toAdmin.getMessage().setString(141, "Y");

            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       log.info("toAdmin: SessionId={}", toAdmin.getSessionId());

    }


    @EventListener
    public void handleFromAdmin(FromAdmin fromAdmin) {
        log.info("fromAdmin: Message={}, SessionId={}", fromAdmin.getMessage(), fromAdmin.getSessionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleToApp(ToApp toApp) {
        log.info("toApp: SessionId={}", toApp.getSessionId());
    }

    @EventListener
public void handleFromApp(FromApp fromApp) {
    log.info("fromApp: Message={}, SessionId={}", fromApp.getMessage(), fromApp.getSessionId());

    try {
                if (fromApp.getMessage().getHeader().getString(35).equals("8")) {
                log.info("It looks we handle ExecutionReport");
//programm doesn't come to this thread =(
            } else {
                log.info("It is not a ExecutionReport message");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It writes to console `ToAdmin`, `FromAdmin`, `toApp`, `fromApp` messages when create session and logon, but it can't handle response for `NewOrderSingle` message.

Could you help me how to handle Execution Report (35=8)?

Comment: The ExecutionReport should be logged inside the `fromApp`, shouldn't it? So can't you just do a check `fromApp.getMessage().getHeader().getString(35).equals("8")` and go on from there?

Comment: @ChristophJohn , thank you for response. I add `if` into `handleFromApp` method, but the programm doesn't come in `true` thread. But it comes in `else`, if message is not `ExecutionReport`.

Comment: Can you add some log output from the `handleFromApp` method? What is the output of the `log.info("fromApp: Message=...."` statement?

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving ExecutionReports at all?

Comment: Yes, because Server Side Company send me log: [14:46:42.258041239] [I] OUT 8=FIX.4.4|9=0247|35=8|.....

Comment: It could be that this message fails validation and is hence not forwarded to the fromApp. Can you check all log files for errors? Or does your toAdmin contain a Reject? MsgType 35=3